# How to use ntp time as default time while using Raspberry Pi as a gateway?

Tags: real-time, ntp, esp8266

I am using Raspberry Pi 4 as a gateway to my esp8266 devices. I have connected ethernet to Raspberry Pi for internet connection. It works fine. I want to generate NTP time in my ESP8266 device.

When I connect the devices to direct Wi-Fi they are getting right time. But when I connect them to Raspberry Pi gateway they are getting date 01.01.1970 .

How to get current date from Raspberry Pi gateway?

Comment: Is the RasPi connected to the internet? Does esp8266 have wired and WiFi interfaces?

Answer (score 3):

[Recent](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/73719/sync-system-clock-with-gps-time-on-systemd-timesyncd) Raspberry Pi OS includes `systemd-timesyncd` as the NTP client. Unfortunately for you, `systemd-timesyncd` does not implement the server functionality, so it cannot provide network time to clients downstream.

You'll have to set up a full-featured NTP server such as `ntp`, `openntpd` or `chrony` (you may disable `systemd-timesyncd`, but you don't have to: it is polite enough not to interfere). Or, if you have any of these set up already, you need to configure them to act as a server.

Comment: I think your answer is correct, which is to say I **interpret** the question as you do. However, I do suggest one correction: There is no need to disable `systemd-timesyncd` - it politely "steps aside" if another NTP server is running. See [this old-ish answer](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/87921/83790), or review `systemctl cat systemd-timesyncd`